# How can I reinitialize a plugin after ajax partial page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need your help. I am working on a social media type website with posts. I refresh the posts every minute. Everything works fine. But I recently added a tooltip plugin. The problem is that the plugin stops working every time I refresh part of the page using ajax. How can I reinitialize my tooltip plugin every time the page is refreshed? I have tried using .on() and I have also tried reinitializing the plugin after the ajax success function. But still no luck. Someone please help.

Here is my refresh posts function:

```
function refreshPosts() // only posts comments likes and count updated.
{   
    var posts = jQuery("#all_post_id").val();   
    var arrays = posts.split(',');
    var dataString = "postids="+posts;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url+"includes/update_wall.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){



        var x = response;
        //############ skip posts whose comments are being read by users
        var ExemptedPostsIDs = jQuery("#ex

emptedPostsID").val();  
                var ExemptedArray    = ExemptedPostsIDs.split(',');
                ExemptedArray = ExemptedArray.sort();
                //////////////

                for(i=0; i<arrays.length; i++) {

                    var val = 'row'+arrays[i];
                    if(x[val])
                    {
                        if(!inArray(arrays[i], ExemptedArray))                                      
                        jQuery("#ajax_wall_"+arrays[i]).html(x[val]);
                    }
                    else
                        jQuery('#PostBoxID'+arrays[i]).parent().fadeOut(500);
                }
            }


   });
}
```

This is where I initialize the plugin:

```
/*----------------activate tooltipster plugin----------------*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tippy-tooltip').tooltipster({
        side: 'top'
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use classnames instead and re-initialize it everytime?

Comment: I am using class names but when the page is refreshed the plugin stops working.

Comment: `on()` is only for events...not plugins. Have to re-initalize on new elements or use a tootip plugin that works using delegation

Comment: Can you show the `html` output of the posts generated by the ajax call?